# Saving image which is displayed using peek() in python

Tags: python

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import sunpy.spectra
  import sunpy.data.sample
  from sunpy.spectra.sources.callisto import CallistoSpectrogram
  image = CallistoSpectrogram.read(sunpy.data.sample.CALLISTO_IMAGE)
  image.peek()
```

Then how to save this image using command?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a SunPy environment to test this on, but can you give the following a shot?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sunpy.spectra
import sunpy.data.sample
from sunpy.spectra.sources.callisto import CallistoSpectrogram
image = CallistoSpectrogram.read(sunpy.data.sample.CALLISTO_IMAGE)
image.plot()
plt.savefig('myfig')
```

Based on [**Generate images without having a window appear**](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#generate-images-without-having-a-window-appear):

> The easiest way to do this is use a non-interactive backend (see What
>   is a backend?) such as Agg (for PNGs), PDF, SVG or PS. In your
>   figure-generating script, just call the matplotlib.use() directive
>   before importing pylab or pyplot:
>
> ```
> import matplotlib
> matplotlib.use('Agg')
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> plt.plot([1,2,3])
> plt.savefig('myfig')
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. That really works. But in peek() I can sent the background vmin=0 as peak(vmin=0), but this is not the case with plot.

Comment: I think you can add the `vmin=0` to your `image.plot()` call. For example: `image.plot(vmin=0)`.  Source:  http://docs.sunpy.org/en/latest/api/sunpy.spectra.spectrogram.Spectrogram.html?#sunpy.spectra.spectrogram.Spectrogram.plot

Comment: Feel free to "accept" the answer if it works for you.  :) Cheers!